# How to create a menu page in my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I don't know how to create a menu page / popup in a chrome extension (not sure if thats actually what its called). I am very new to coding chrome extensions, and I was wondering how to create a new page in my chrome extension, just like in a website in which you click a button and it brings you to a different page within the website. This is a screenshot of the 2048 menu page on chrome ->[2048 Menu Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BYYJ.png) and im not sure how to create a page like that. I am creating a button-pressing game, and I want my menu page to pop up first when the chrome extension icon is clicked, and then there is a list of options like hardcore, begginer etc. and a button to bring me to the game page itself, but still in the same popup, with the same dimensions, exactly like 2048. Does it have something to do with the popups, the manifest.json file? Im really not sure...

Here is the [Screenshot of my manifest.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toI7u.png) and here is the [Screenshot of popup.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q91T.png). If anyone knows how to do this, or needs any extra info, please let me know

PS: Pls explain and show me step by step like im a kindergarden kid, cuz at this stage in my coding skills i probs am ngl.

Comment: The questions is unanswerable because it's too broad. Start by reading the [official introduction into extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/overview/) which contains all the info you need and a walk-through tutorial for creating an extension. There may be better tutorials.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Oh im sorry if i was being vague , i just want to be able to make more than one popup that opens when a button is clicked. Right now, they only allow one popup, which "default_popup"... do you get what im saying? @wOxxOm